# Why am I required to await a call when it's already been await'ed (.NET Core 2.2)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

I have the service method returning an awaitable member view model.

```
public async Task<MemberVm> GetMember(Guid id)
{
  Task<Member> output = Context.Members
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);

  return await output != null
    ? new MemberVm(output)
    : null;
}
```

This doesn't compile because of `new MemberVm(output)`. Instead, the computer requires me to do `new MemberVm(await output)`. I would understand it if it was a simple return statement but in this case it's already been awaited while evaluation the conditional expression. To me it seems like this pseudo-code.

```
if(await output != null)
  return await-again-but-why new MemberVm(output)
else
  return null;
```

Am I doing it wrong or is it just an unintended and unfortunate consequence of the language syntax?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you asked the same thing in the morning. The answer is stil the same - await the *task* to get the result. `output` is a *task*, not the actual output of the operation. Use `Member output= await Context.Members.SingleOrDefaultAsync(e=>e.Id==id)`

Comment: Also `output` will never be `null` because SingleOrDefaultAsync (or any async call in the framework) will never return a null value. Only the result of the Task could produce a `null` value.

Comment: default(MemberVm) isn't null?

Comment: You cant await null even if you awaited the call in the constructor.

Comment: You need `await` to "unwrap" the value from a `Task` inside an `async` function. This unwrapping doesn't happen in-place, your `output` remains the same value as it was originally.

Comment: @peaceoutside `output` cannot be null. `await output` can.

Comment: @fildor oh okay, yeah, I knew that, I guess I was just confused about what `output` was in this context.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I asked another question, the result of which led me to this. Apologies if it's not apparent - let me elaborate. I wonder specifically how how a result that's been awaited (in the if clause) needs to be additionally awaited (in the true statement). I understand I can await it already in the first statement (and not need to await it in the if statement) but that's expected. What wasn't expected is that if I await it in the condition of `if`, I need to await it again. I didn't have to await again if I awaited in the first statement. Why should I do it twice here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't compile because `output` is a `Task`, not a `Member`.

This would work:

```
public async Task<MemberVm> GetMember(Guid id)
{
  Member member = await Context.Members
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);

  return member != null
    ? new MemberVm(member)
    : null;
}
```

This doesn't :

```
Task<Member> output = Context.Members
                             .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);

return await output != null // <= "await output" is null or a Member instance
    ? new MemberVm(output)  // "output" is always a Task<Member>
    : null;
```

By writing `await output` "ouput" itself will not be replaced by the result of the await. It is still the same reference to the Task you created above.

---

Unrelated: I wouldn't recommend returning `null`. I guess I'd have `MemberVM` deal with being setup with `null` or throw an exception if this is a strong indication something is wrong with the application code or DB consistency.

Comment: Oh, I think I start to see where I went wrong. Just to verify that I'm set straight. I could use `new MemberVm(output.Value)`, once I'm sure it's been awaited thanks to the conditional statement. Correct? (Of course, it's not recommended to do so and it's just an example to probe if I'm getting it right.) Also, thanks for the remark on returning `null`. I'll see how I can refactor the code in my project.

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't read how `async..await` works, you probably should to reason about it better; but what those keywords primarily do is trigger an automagical rewrite of your original code into continuation-passing style.

What basically happens is your original code is transformed into:

```
public Task<MemberVm> GetMember(Guid id)
{
    Task<Member> output = Context.Members
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
    return output.ContinueWith((Task<Member> awaitedOutput) => 
        awaitedOutput.Result != null ? new MemberVm(output.Result) : null);
}
```

The original `output` variable remains untouched, the result of the await (so to speak) is passed into the continuation when it's available. Since you're not saving it into a variable, it's not available to you after it's first used. (It's the lambda parameter I called `awaitedOutput`, it's actually probably going to be something garbled the C# compiler generates if you don't assign the awaited output to a variable yourself.)

In your case it's probably easiest to just store the awaited value in the variable

```
public Task<MemberVm> GetMember(Guid id)
{
    Member output = await Context.Members
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
    return output != null
        ? new MemberVm(output)
        : null;
}
```

You could also probably use `output.Result` directly in the code under the `await`, but that's not really how you're supposed to do things and it's slightly error-prone. (If you reassign `output` inadvertently to a different task for some reason. This would cause the whole thread to `Wait()`, and my guess is it'd just freeze.)

---

Crucially, it *doesn't make any sense* to say "a call that's already been awaited". Under the hood, await isn't a thing you **do** to a call or a task; it's an instruction to the compiler to take all the code following the await, pack it up into a closure, pass that to `Task.ContinueWith()`, and *immediately* return the new task. That is: await doesn't in and of itself cause a wait for the result of the call, it causes the waiting code to be registered as a callback to be invoked whenever the result is available. If you await a Task whose result is already available, all that changes is that this callback will be called sooner.

The way this achieves asynchrony is that control returns to some event loop outside your code at every point where you need to wait for a call to complete. This event loop watches for stuff to arrive "from the outside" (e.g. some I/O operation completing), and wakes up whatever continuation chain is waiting for this. When you `await` the same `Task` more than once, all that happens is that it handles several such callbacks.

(Hypothetically, yes, the compiler could also transform the code so that following an await, the original variable name refers to the new value. But there's a bunch of reasons why I imagine it's not implemented that way - the type of a variable changing mid-function is unprecedented in C# and would be confusing; and generally it seems like it'd be more complex and harder to reason about overall.)

---

Going on a hopefully illustrative tangent here: what I believe more or less happens when you `await` a Task in the same `async` function twice is:

1. Execution reaches the first await, a callback (which contains is created and passed to `ContinueWith()`, control returns to toplevel.
2. Some time later, the result of the call is available, and the callback ends up invoked with the result as the parameter.
3. Execution of the first callback reaches the second await, another callback is created and passed to `ContinueWith()`
4. Since the result is already available, this second callback is probably invoked immediately, and the rest of your function runs.

As you can see, awaiting the same Task twice is mostly a pointless detour through the event loop. If you need the value of the task, just put it into a variable. In my experience, a lot of the time you might as well immediately `await` a call to any `async` function, and move this statement as close to where the task result is used as you can. (Since any code after the await won’t run until after the result is available, even if it’s not using that result.) The exception is if you have some code you need to run after starting the call, but before using the result, that you can't just run before the call starts for some reason.

Comment: It helped me to think of it like the legacy async, where you'd have "StartAsyncCall" and everything after the await goes into "EndAsyncCall".

Comment: Yeah. It's also like Javascript Promise chaining which might be familiar to people. But really the crux of what `async..await` does is restructure code written using familiar imperative control flow into the sort of code you'd have to write manually when using legacy async or Promises. In C# there's a whole bunch of stuff around the edges of this idea, like making loops work and debugging this and being able to schedule a continuation on a different thread than where it was triggered from but they're not really what the language feature is about.

Comment: This is a really exhaustive and informative answer. I've accepted answer of @Fildor because it's shorter and points out specifically the spot where I stumbled and fell on my thinking. However, the effort you've put I'm was beneficial to me in a broader aspect and I'm sure it will be to others as well. So I'll do something that the stingy duck like (almost) never does and bounty you. Your answer deserves it.

Comment: But you'll have to hold your ponies for the bounty - it says two days. I'll try to remember but if I don't, please send me a beep.

Answer (score 3):

There's already correct answers here, but the explanations are far more complex than necessary. The `await` keyword both holds execution until the task completes *and* unwraps the task (i.e `Task<Member>` becomes just `Member`). However, you're not *persisting* that unwrapping part.

The second `output` is still a `Task<Member>`. It's completed now, but it isn't unwrapped because you didn't save the result of that.

Comment: Yeah, once @fidor showed that with an arrow, I saw it immediately. And I can't believe how I could have missed that before. Somehow, in my head, awaiting stuff made them unwrap and re-type the object. It makes no sense now that I spell it out but that what my brains held for sweet truth this morning. Stupid...

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

What does the constructor for MemberVm look like?

```
public async Task<MemberVm> GetMember(Guid id)
{
  var output = await Context.Members
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);

  if (output == null)
     return null;

  return new MemberVm(output);
}
```

It would seem that the constructor for MemberVm doesn't take a Task param in its constructor (although without seeing the code, I can't tell for sure). Instead, I think the constructor needs just a regular MemberVm param, so by evaluating the Context.Members... call before anything else, should help fix what you have going on. If not, let me know and we'll figure it out.

Comment: The constructor of *MemberVm* takes *Member*, not *Task<Member>*. So I understand that *output* needs to to be awaited to get to the value of the task. But I thought, possibly incorrectly, that once we executed an await on the task, hence fetching its value, there won't be any need for re-awating as the value's already there, pre-awaited for. Maybe I'm mistaken in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand the the problem that the compiler flagging is a type problem. The `MemberVm` constructor takes a `Member` argument, but your `output` variable is of type `Task<Member>`. The compiler doesn't really want you to await for the Task again, but that is the most common way to extract the result from a Task and make the types work. Another way to rewrite your code is by changing the type of `output`:

```
Member output = await Context.Members.SingleOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
```

Now you can pass `output` directly to the `MemberVm` constructor, because you've saved the result of the first await.